# How can I to connect to a Docker running mysql?

Tags: mysql, docker

The instructions here: https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql indicate to run

```
$ docker run -it --network some-network --rm mysql mysql -hsome-mysql-container -uexample-user -p
```

But i have no idea what some-network is?  So i run this instead and get and 'unknown MySQL host' error even though some-mysql-container is definitely the name of my container.

```
$ docker run -it--rm mysql mysql -hsome-mysql-container -uexample-user -p
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

'some-network' refers to a docker-network. You need to create it first. I named it 'mysql-network' to make its purpose a bit more clear:

```
docker network create mysql-network
```

Then, start database container:

```
docker run --network mysql-network --name mysql-db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d mysql
```

Then, start a the client container to connect to the first one:

```
docker run -it --network mysql-network --rm mysql mysql -hmysql-db -uroot -p
```

By adding both containers to the same network, they are able to communicate with each other.